# multiple rewriterole url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo

I have two language for my website. (`en/fr`). `en` is default language and i show with this url :

```
mydomain.com/
mydomain.com/news.php?id=XX
```

For second language i have this url :

```
mydomain.com/index.php?lang=fr
```

now i rewrite url using `.htaccess` like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(fr)(/)?$  index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((fr)/)news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ news.php?id=$1 [L]
```

now in output :

```
mydomain.com  <-- WORKED defualt
mydomain.com/fr/  <-- WORKED defualt 
mydomain.com/fr/news/id/title.html  <-- WORKED show news in fr language
mydomain.com/news/id/title.html   <-- for default language NOT WORKED
```

For default language (`mydomain.com/news/id/title.html`) not work. How do can i fix this problem ?

**NOTE**: for default language i don't need to add `/en/` to url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(fr)(/)?$  index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((fr)/)news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ news.php?id=$2&lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ news.php?id=$1 [L]
```

You're missing the rule that rewrites without the `/fr/` in front.

Comment: Sure, Your code worked. but i have many page (gallery.php, contact.php, faq.php , ...) and for two and three language i need to write many .htaccess code!!

Comment: if i put default language in url this is bad idea(seo)? example : `mydomain.com/en/news/id/title.html `

Comment: @PinkCode it's not bad as long as you always have `/en/`